# Problem with selenium does not load page after some time

Tags: python, selenium

I have made a simple code, which I scrape recipes from one site. The url of every recipe is written on an excel and I read it with pandas. I have a weird problem there, for example I want to scrape 100 recipes, when the for goes to i = 21 it breaks and does not load the page (infinite loading of the site), but when I start the for loop from 20 it breaks on 41. Rerun the code and can break on i = 17, it's pretty random.
Does anyone has this similar problem?
website: https://akispetretzikis.com/en
thank you

```
def mainProgram(start):
    now = datetime.now()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')                                                                        
    theDictionary = {"Link": [], "Name": [], "Time": [], "Difficulty": [],     
                     "Merides": [], "Ingredients": [],
                     "ThermidesPer100gr": [], "ThermidesAnaMerida": []}
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', 
                              options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1280, 960)                                                
    thePath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "ScrapeRecipes",   
                           "Cooking"+str(now.year)+".xlsx")
    thePathReadExcel = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", 
                                    "CookingUrls"+str(now.year)+".xlsx")
    UrlOfRecipes = readExcel(thePath=thePathReadExcel)


    try:
        Length = len(UrlOfRecipes)
        print(Length)
        Length = 100#e.g. 100 actual Length over 1k
        for i in range(start, Length, 1):
            driver.delete_all_cookies()
            driver.get(UrlOfRecipes["Link"][i])
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20 + round(random.uniform(0, 4), 2))
            time.sleep(30 + round(random.uniform(0, 4), 2))  # mandatory sleep
            theDictionary["Link"].append(UrlOfRecipes["Link"][i])
            theDictionary = getDataFromRecipe(driver, theDictionary)
            time.sleep(20 + round(random.uniform(0, 4), 2))
            print(i)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        writeOnExcel(theDict, thePath)
```

Comment: not much you can do with an infinitely loading page.  Eventually the page load will timeout (you can set that period to be shorter if needed)  At that point you need to use another .get().  On a side note, there's no point in your "wait = webdriverwait..." line.  Remove that.   Random sleeps won't be useful either.  Just set it to a fixed amount.   You probably also want to show your getDataFromRecipe method.  Not likely, but it's possible there's something in there causing the infinite loading.

Comment: the random sleeps is just to look as less ican as a bot. the function getDataFromRecipe  it's just read's 4 xpaths nothing else.t

Comment: anyone has some idea? I am bit stacked